# Import Automation - 'File Not Found' error

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I am doing a file import activity into a DE with file drop trigger. While building the import activity, the file naming pattern determines this pattern FILENAME_%%Month%%%%Day%%%%year%%.csv
Unfortunately, when we activate and drop the file into FTP, it's failing with File not found error. 
If I give the exact filename, it works!
I don't know why the wild cards are not being picked.

Comment: Which folder did you choose for file drop? Are you sure you’re dropping the file into the correct folder? You also don’t need the .csv extension, put just the filename with wildcards.

Comment: I literally just had this problem and it ended up being a user error on my part. In the Import File Activity, I selected the wrong folder for it to look into.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% and then setting up a filter in the automation settings (file drop automation type) where you will find 3 main options/filters for "Use Filename Pattern":

1. Contains
2. Begins with
3. Ends with

[image]

More about substitution strings: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_substitution_strings_example.htm&type=5

Comment: I have done this part, but still only in the file import activity, am facing this issue

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the problematic part?

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 steps to debug:

1. Put in the name in your **file drop** activity as CONTAINS FILENAME_ (don't add timestamp and file extension for testing) and select correct folder
2. In your **Import File Activity** use name matching as %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%
   and *again* select the correct folder.

This should tell you if there is datetime mismatch on the timestamp.

Also know that you can test the File Drop trigger by renaming your file name *and* uploading as new file. The trigger won't work if you simply rename the file in SFMC SFTP.